# Unable to get property 'LTIOV' of undefined or null reference

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, error

I am using this code to retrieve data from my sharepoint list. Regardless of my Null check I still get the error saying unable to get property or null reference.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + requestUri,
        type: "GET",
        async:false,
    headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data.d.results, function (i, item){
                    var stat = item.MijnStatus;
                    var ltiov = item.LTIOV;
                    var reply = item.Reply;
                    var periode = item.Jaar;
            if (periode == myYear || stat == 'Completed') {
                console.log(ltiov);
                console.log(reply);
                                     if (reply != null){
                                        xValues.push(item[i].Reply);
                                      }
                                     if (ltiov != null){
                                        xValues.push(item[i].LTIOV);
                                      }
                var randomColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
                        barColors.push(randomColor);

            }
               // fnGenerateChart(xValues, yValues);
                })

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Something went wrong");
            }                     
        });
```

Comment: At which line are you getting this error? Instead of using `item[i].LTIOV`, try using `item.LTIOV`. Let me know if this works?

Comment: Ganesh indeed this works! The only thing not working is this line: if (periode == myYear || stat == 'Completed') . I still get all items also the ones not Completed.

Comment: You are using **OR**(`||`) operator in condition. Are you sure you want that? You are getting items that are not completed because those items satisfies first condition (`periode == myYear`). If you want both conditions to satisfy, use `if (periode == myYear && stat == 'Completed')`.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks a lot!

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this error, use `item.LTIOV` instead of using `item[i].LTIOV` as you are getting complete list item object in `item` variable inside for each loop.

**Updated from comments**:

To get only "Completed" items, use if condition like below:

```
if (periode == myYear && stat == 'Completed') {  }
```